# Creating a Groupby Grand Total row for %

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a DataFrame in which I am calculating the complete % based on two columns within the DataFrame, grouped by "NAME".

I would like to add a Grand Total column, but don't know where to start with this.

DataFrame:

```
    Name  Attempts Completes
0    A       6        5
1    B       5        4
2    B       2        2
3    A       9        7
```

Code that I am using to calculate %:

```
df.groupby('Name')['Completes'].sum() / df.groupby('Name')['Attempts'].sum()
```

Result:

```
Name
A    0.800000
B    0.857143
dtype: float64
```

Result I am after:

```
Name
A       0.800000
B       0.857143
Grand Total 0.818181
dtype: float64
```

Thanks in advance for any advice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just need assign it back

```
s=df.groupby('Name')['Completes'].sum() / df.groupby('Name')['Attempts'].sum()
s.loc['Grand Total']=df['Completes'].sum()/df['Attempts'].sum()
s
Out[312]: 
Name
A              0.800000
B              0.857143
Grand Total    0.818182
dtype: float64
```

Answer (score 2):

You can also group it using pivot_table, which has the grand total option.

[image]